# Как поддерживать проект после сборки gulp?

Tags: gulp, frontend, npm

Имеется такая структура проекта:

```
-app
  -scss
    - 1.scss
    - 2.scss
    - 3.scss
  -js
    - 1.js
    - 2.js
    - 3.js
  - index.html

-dist
  -css
    - style.min.css
  -js
    - scripts.min.js
  - index.html
```

app соответственно исходники, а dist это уже объединенные и минифицированные файлы.
Собственно вопрос: как поддерживать такой проект если на хостинге будет лежать только папка dist? Ведь там только .min файлы) или на хостинг закидывать еще и папку app, либо хранить ее где-то отдельно?

Comment: эм.... на хостинг кидаются минифицированные файлы, а разработка идёт в нормальных. Так что нет проблем с поддержкой

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это понятно, ну например мне дали задачу что-то изменить в стилях на сайте, а на хостинге только .min.css . Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: и что, они не предоставляют исходников или доступ по git/bitbucket/sftp/хз?))